# Partial Differential Equation with Travelling Wave Solutions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function. Consider the partial differential equation:
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f(u(x))}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^{3} u}{\partial x^{3}}=0
$$
I wish to find the solutions of the form $u(x, t)=\phi(x-c t)$ (traveling wave solutions) where $\phi$ is a smooth function. Then I am asked to integrate the obtained ODE, any help would be much appreciated since I am completely lost especially in the substitution process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We first set $\gamma=x-\alpha t$. Then we obtain the ordinary differential
equation
$$
-\alpha \frac{d \phi}{d \gamma}+f(\phi(\gamma))\frac{d \phi}{d \gamma}+\frac{d^{3} \phi}{d \gamma^{3}}=0.
$$
Integrating once we arrive at
$$
-\alpha \phi+f(\phi(\gamma))+\frac{d^{2} \phi}{d \gamma^{2}}=C_{1}
$$
where $C_{1}$ is a constant of integration. One more integration yields
$$
\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{d \phi}{d \gamma}\right)^{2}=C_{2}+C_{1} \phi+\frac{\alpha}{2} \phi^{2}-F(\phi(\gamma)), \quad F(\phi)=\int_{0}^{\phi} f(y) d y
$$
Where $C_{2}$ is another constant of integration.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!